# Mysterious Padding / Margin Around Images

Tags: html, css

Please see the following jsFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/Leng/kQvNH/

Can anyone explain why there appears to be a substantial amount of padding (approx. 15px above and 4px below) around every line of horizontal dots?  The images are only 2px tall.  Where is the padding coming from?

**PLEASE NOTE:**

For me, this mysterious padding around images is **only happening** when I begin my documents with the HTML5 heading:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
```

Images **display normally** (no padding) when I use -*any other*- header, such as HTML4 or this XHTML heading for a webpage:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

So this appears to be an HTML5 inconsistency.  I would like to switch to the standard HTML5 headings, but this little annoyance is preventing me from doing so.

Thank you for any guidance.

**THE SOLUTION:**

Here is the jsFiddle with the solution:  http://jsfiddle.net/Leng/Sn2PC/

```
img
{
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

This is based on Chris's answer below.

*Please note that setting font-size:0 or line-height:0 is **not** a solution, because that messes (obviously) with the font size and line height.*

And again, setting the display to block and establishing an auto-margin was not necessary to accomplish normal, centered, un-padded images in HTML4 or XHTML.

HTML5 has created this "feature", where images are inline and will have padding based on line-height or font-size.

Comment: If you make them `float: left;` the padding is removed :-)

Comment: I don't want floated images, I want relatively positioned images.

Comment: try setting `line-height: 0` on the div

Comment: @tborychowski, thanks.  That is not the cleanest solution, because you may have text that you want formatted properly.  The cleanest solution is in the jsFiddle I've added to my question based on Chris's answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is because the `img` elements are inline.  Setting the `font-size` or `line-height` to something small fixes this.  Alternatively, set the images to `display: block` and set a height on them.

Comment: `display: block` will probably be the cleanest solution

Comment: Thank you, Chris.  Here they are displaying normally with your advice:  http://jsfiddle.net/yY9rx/

I wonder why setting the display for images is only necessary for HTML5?  It wasn't necessary for HTML4 or XHTML.

Comment: My pleasure, glad you got it working.

Comment: I would go for ```display: inline-block;```

Answer (score 1):

Your `<img>` tag is displayed INLINED, so it goes with normal text.
Just change the line-height of your container to something closer to image height and font-size ( 1px) will fix this.

So, to explain the padding, there is no padding around your images. It an empty line of text with it's height (line-height) defined by the user-agent.

[fiddled here](http://jsfiddle.net/QbkXs/2/)

Comment: The solution is to change display to block for the images, because there is unnecessary padding in yours as well.  See how much closer they are in this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/yY9rx/

Comment: If you had added a font-size:1px, that would have done the trick, though.  But again, we don't want to mess with fonts, which is why we're using display:block instead.

Comment: You are right, i forgot the font-size somewhere ..

Answer (score 0):

You can add a line-height:2px; to #theDiv style